# Rails: Tidy Stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

Anyone know how to take the awesome method mentioned in [this](http://the-banana-peel.saltybanana.com/2008/06/tidy-stylesheets-take-two.html) tutorial and have the stylesheet tags generate with **absolute URLs**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In what goes in the application_helper.rb:

```
def get_stylesheets
  stylesheets = [] unless stylesheets
  ["http://www.example.com/stylesheets/#{controller.controller_path}/#{controller.action_name}"].each do |ss|
    stylesheets << ss if File.exists? "#{Dir.pwd}/public/stylesheets/#{ss}.css"
  end
end
```

Works as advertised. Nice!

I've been wanting to do this for ages - now thanks to Rails I can!  Woohoo!